# Get the intersect of two list with specific criteria

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have two list of Cars

List1:

- "Ferrari",2005,"$350,000"
- "BMW",2009,"$29,000"
- "Audi",2011,"$33,000"

List2:

- "Infinity",2005,"$267,000"
- "BMW",2009,"$45,000"
- "Ferrari",2005,"$330,000"
- "Toyota",2009,"$35,000"

I know that I can get a list of duplicate cars by using the Intersect method. But I would like to also keep the one that has the smaller price. For example I want some method that will return:

- "Ferrari",2005,"$330,000"
- "BMW",2009,"$29,000"

because those are the cars that repeat with name and they have the smallest price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely untested, but how about something like this?

```
var result = from c1 in List1
             join c2 in List2 on c1.Name equals c2.Name
             select new CarInfo()
             {
                 Name = c1.Name, // Doesn't really matter which you take
                 Year = c1.Price < c2.Price ? c1.Year : c2.Year,
                 Price = c1.Price < c2.Price ? c1.Price : c2.Price
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? I'm assuming you have the CarComparer IEquality bit for the Intersect.

```
var cheapCars = list1.Intersect(list2, new CarComparer()).
    OrderBy(c => c.Price).
        GroupBy(c => c.Name).
            Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

You might have to fix syntax...

Answer (score 0):

The following query will match cars on `Brand` and `Year` properties. If you only care about the `Brand`, you can alter the join criteria to meet that purpose.

```
var results = from car1 in list1
              join car2 in list2 
                on new { car1.Brand, car1.Year } 
                equals new { car2.Brand, car2.Year }
              select (car1.Price <= car2.Price) ? car1 : car2;
```